# Share jar of the module with another team

Tags: maven, dependencies, hudson, repository, artifactory

I am new to maven and trying to figure out how to share the jar file of the module with our another team. They are developing another module and their module depends on our module.

Will it be the best solution to setup 3rd party maven remote repository ?
What will be the correct tools for this?

We use Hudson to manage our integration environment build. And I started looking into Artifactory and Artifactory plugin for Hudson. Is it correct approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 main Maven repository managers to consider:

- [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)
- [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php)
- [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/)

Personally, I would recommend Nexus.

A left field option to consider is the [Jenkins Maven repository](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Maven+Repository+Server) plugin. This enables the jar built by Jenkins to be published as a Maven module. (Hudson and Jenkins plugins should still be compatible)

Answer (score 0):

Yes have a look at using a corporate repository manager to deploy your artifacts and share it with other teams.
You have:

- artifactory
- nexus
- apache archiva