# Including the Jar of a Maven Project in another Maven Project does not work but including the Project in another Maven Project works

Tags: java, exception, maven, maven-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I have 2 Projects namely `Project_1` and `Project_2`.
Both projects are `Maven` and I am using Netbeans.

I want to include the jar of `Project_1` in `Project_2` which I am doing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473537/how-to-include-jar-in-maven-netbeans-proj-that-doesnt-exist-in-maven-repo).

The problem is when I include the jar I do not get any compile time error, however I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` exception at runtime.

When I include the `Project_1` in `Project_2` by performing the steps mentioned [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/07/add-maven-dependency-in-netbeans.html). (The Open Project example). I do not get any errors. Neither runtime nor compile time.

Can you please explain me what am I missing here?

**Update**

`Project_2` is deployed on a Server which is not in my local machine however `Project_1` is in my local machine.

Inclusion of `Project_1` into `Project_2` as a project was done for testing in my local machine.

Comment: After doing the second option, it will also add an entry in pom.xml. Please look into it what it has added in <dependency> tag

Comment: @rizzz86 the scope and systemPath are missing if i include the project.

Comment: So that means if you add the <dependency> tag manually without scope and systemPath then it will also work ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201195/share-jar-of-the-module-with-another-team/9202409#9202409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a good rule of thumb to adopt is never use the [system scope and system path](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) to pull in dependencies. In my experience there's always a better way :-)

If Project_2 depends on Project_1, then first install it's jar into the local repository:

```
   cd Project_1
   mvn clean install
```

Watch the output you'll discover the jar is placed somewhere under the following directory:

```
   $HOME/.m2/repository
```

Once this is done the jar will be available as a normal dependency to the second build

```
  cd Project_2
  mvn clean compile
```

The local repository ensures the projects are now decoupled from each other. Assuming you're using snapshot revisions of Project_1, the Project_2 build will always retrieve the latest revision built and tested.

## Update

You should use a [Maven repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) to share jars between machines/teams. Recommendations are contained in the following answer:

[Share jar of the module with another team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201195/share-jar-of-the-module-with-another-team/9202409#9202409)

How to configure Maven to use a repository like Nexus is described in it's [documentation](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html).

As described in the [deploy plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) you'll need to add a *distributionManagement* section to your POM (detailing the repository URL) and then upload the project's jar to your repository as follows:

```
   cd Project_1
   mvn clean deploy
```

Comment: Thank you however there is issue. The `Project_1` is a project in my local computer and `Project_2` is a project deployed in a server. To include `Project_1`'s jar in `Project_2` i have to place the `Project_1`'s jar somewhere in the server and include it in `Project_2`.

Comment: @Juniad Then you need to install a Maven repository manager and use this to deploy build output and pull dependencies. Highly recommended when you're sharing jars and will also improve the performance of your builds. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201195/share-jar-of-the-module-with-another-team/9202409#9202409